# Remove extra non-working scanners

Tags: arch-linux, devices, scanner, uninstall

I tried to add a USB scanner to my system without any luck and now when I start **XSane** or **Image Scan! for Linux** I get a list of non-working scanners. How these can be removed?

I've tried:

```
# pacman -Rsc iscan iscan-data sane xsane 
# rm -rf ~/.sane
# rm -rf ~/.xsane
# rm -rf /etc/sane.d
```

and after re-installing packages the old devices are still found. I've booted many times.

```
# sane-find-scanner                                                                                        (10-06 19:05)

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.
  # Also you need support for SCSI Generic (sg) in your operating system.
  # If using Linux, try "modprobe sg".

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x013d [Epson Perfection V39]) at libusb:004:003
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

Scanner is detected.

```
# scanimage -L                                                                                             (10-06 19:07)
device `epkowa:interpreter:004:003' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
device `epkowa:interpreter:004:003' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
device `epkowa:interpreter:004:003' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
device `epkowa:interpreter:004:003' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
device `epkowa:interpreter:004:003' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
```

lsusb:

```
# lsusb | grep -i epson                                                                                    (10-06 19:10)
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 04b8:013d Seiko Epson Corp.
```

Commands for adding scanner with wrong firmware `.bin` files are lost.

Comment: Please paste the "list of non-working scanners", and the command you have used.

Comment: @FaheemMitha added more details.